# Select column from similarly named tables

Tags: mysql, sql-like, tablename

I want to select a specific column form many tables that have similar names i.e.:

Tables Names

x1

x2

x3

y1

y2

z1

smth like this : select `field` from like x%;

all tables have the same structure and column names